# Why swap is touched when zswap is enabled and zswap pool is not full?

Tags: swap

current configurations is 
swappiness = 40;
zswap cache = 40

`free -m` command says

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3615        1353        1232         191        1029        1806
Swap:          4095           4        4091
```

zswap debug info by command `sudo grep -r . /sys/kernel/debug/zswap`

```
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/stored_pages:892
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/pool_total_size:1220608
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/duplicate_entry:0
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/written_back_pages:0
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/reject_compress_poor:0
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/reject_kmemcache_fail:0
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/reject_alloc_fail:0
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/reject_reclaim_fail:0
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/pool_limit_hit:0
```

Comment: I've just been testing and have seen the system go massively into swap without hitting the pool limit. Very odd. I've spent an hour reading the source and still can't see how this could happen...

Answer (score 5):

Pages in zswap still get counted as disk swapped.
I believe this is needed because the zswap pool size is dynamic and this allows to eventually move all pages to the disk swap.

/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/written_back_pages shows how many pages where actually written to disk, but as far as I understand this is an all time cumulative increment.

To get the **current number of bytes swapped on disk** :

You want to calculate

```
$used_swap_in_bytes(as shown by "free -b" or "swapon -s") -
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/stored_pages * $(getconf PAGESIZE)
```

eg (in bytes)

```
echo "$(LANG=c free -b |grep Swap |awk '{print $3}') - $(sudo \
cat /sys/kernel/debug/zswap/stored_pages)*$(getconf PAGESIZE)" |bc -l
echo bytes swapped on disk
```

or in Mio (floor rounded ):

```
echo | awk '{value='"$(LANG=c free -b |grep Swap |awk '{print $3}')\
- $(sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/zswap/stored_pages)*\
$(getconf PAGESIZE)"';printf "%.0f\n", value/1024**2}'
echo Mio swapped on disk
```